# Need help identifying large shrub or tree? Approx 8 feet tall

Tags: berries

San antonio TX. This was not planted to my knowledge. Has clusters of small (sl bigger than pea) dark blue berries currently (feb 15th, weather in 60s daytime, maybe 40s at night). Leaves are lens-shaped green, smooth and firm. Have puppy who eats everything. Worried it is poisonous.

Comment: Try to upload pics if possible. Visual cues help to identify better.